# Date picker in Magento product custom option gives only date. Need date and time

Tags: php, magento, datepicker

I add a `custom option` for my product.
`Input type` for `custom option` is **Date & Time.**

To avoid dropdown and display date picker in product page I change:

`Use JavaScript Calendar  to "yes"` in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Date&Time Custom Options >`

But the `datepicker gives date only` not time. `I need date and time.`The drop down box for select time is still shown. I want avoid this dropdown.

Is there any way to give the datepicker both date and time.

[image]

**Magento version 1.9.0.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `input type` for `custom option` to `Date`.
And in **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Date.php** file change the code as below

```
var calendarSetupObject = {
                inputField  : "' . $this->getId() . '",
                ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%e %H:%M:%S", //changed line
                showsTime: true,               //changed line
                button      : "' . $this->getId() . '_trig",
                align       : "Bl",
                singleClick : true,
```

Now we can select both date and time from the date picker and can avoid the drop down for time.

Comment: but in checkout page shows only selected date not time. How can I solve this??

Comment: You should never change code in core files. Instead of you should find a way to overwrite this setup in a custom module.

Comment: How Do i restrict the past date and  restrict date range e.g allow date selection from month of november to january